# React Native: How do I onPress interact with a child button of an Animated.View parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to solve this for ages now, I've posted here before and was given generic copy-paste from other places I've visited / looked at. I've stripped the component down to nothing but the gestures and the render. I'm really not getting how this is supposed to work.

There is an `Animated.View`. It has a child `TouchableOpacity`.

1. I can move the `Animated.View` around with pan gestures.
2. When I press the `TouchableOpacity` there is a (small) random chance that I will get the response from the `onPress` console.log().

Am I missing something still? I need the button to log to the console every time it's pressed, not 5% of the time. It's unreliable.

Suggestions? Advice? Is this not something that can actually be done in React native?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  PanResponder
} from "react-native";

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    pan: new Animated.ValueXY()
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,

      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }
      ]),

      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        const positionY = this.state.pan.y.__getValue();
        if (positionY > 200) {
          Animated.timing(this.state.pan, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 1000 }
          }).start(() => {
            this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
          });
        } else {
          Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 }
          }).start();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  sayHello = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          { height: 150, width: 150, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "orange" },
          {
            transform: [
              { translateX: this.state.pan.x },
              { translateY: this.state.pan.y }
            ]
          }
        ]}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ height: 100, width: 100, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "red" }}
          onPress={() => console.log("hello?")}
        >
          <Text style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "blue" }}>
            Hello
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Animated.View
    style={[
      { height: 150, width: 150, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "orange" },
      {            transform: [
          { translateX: this.state.pan.x },
          { translateY: this.state.pan.y }
        ]
      }
    ]}
    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
  >
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{flex : 1, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "red" }}
      onPress={() => console.log("hello?")}
    >
      <Text style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "blue" }}>
        Hello
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>
);
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answers the question.